# How to debug HTTP Error 503 - Jetty

Tags: java, gwt, jetty

My gwt application is throwing:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
RequestURI=/App.html
```

When accessed. How do I debug more details on the this `Error 503`, where I know there must be some problems with the configuration, however where can I find the error logs when running with `$mvn gwt:run` which fires up a embedded jetty.

Comment: IIRC, this means your webapp couldn't be deployed: your web.xml links to a nonexistent class, a servlet or servlet context listener throws when initialized; but there should be something in the logs. Maybe you could share the whole logs?

Comment: Actually the logs shows nothing about any error, that is why i am really confused about this, except for 00:00:00.000 [ERROR] 503 - GET /App.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 (127.0.0.1) 1315 bytes

Comment: IIRC, the deployment errors are output to the console, not the DevMode window.

Comment: @thomas-broyer There's no error message in the eclipse console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
$mvn verify -DskipTests=true
$mvn clean package
$mvn gwt:run
```

Then it can now fetch the gwt html file.